# Jira, Component specific outgoing email address

Tags: components, jira, email

I have some problem with the latest Jira (4.3.4). In this version you can set a specific outgoing email address in every project. That's a great feature. But I want to go even further and give every component a specific outgoing email address to. Why? Because we have our Support in one project and every different support customer has their own component representing them.

Every support customer have their own email address ex, support-*customer*@*.*. It is to this address we want them to email. But the Jira system as it works right now emails from a no-reply address. And a project specific address wouldn't do it either. Thats because we have a mailerdaemon which task is to modify the subject to JEMH (Jira Extentable Mail Handler) valid subjects. That mailerdaemon checks the To: address to add the right component.This works great and every issue gets their specific component.

Wanted scenario.
customer emails to address support-*customer*@*.*. Mailerdaemon picks the mail up and formats the subject. JEMH read the formatted email and creates the issue. Jira emails the customer that the issue is created using From: support-*customer*@*.*.

Same as commented and so on.

Answer (score 0):

A potential approach would be to create a specific listener which sends a mail to the component lead.
An approach is using the script runner

Check out the example script to construct the email 
https://studio.plugins.atlassian.com/wiki/display/GRV/Post+Functions#PostFunctions-SendEmailWhenBlockerReported

Logic to retrieve the component lead is straightforward.  Getting the email address from the component lead also.

The listener would only act on 'my-create-event'.  the my-create-event is included in the workflow create transition ...

Francis